# Filter search results by array of ids

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am planning to implement a search filter by an array of ids using Azure Cognitive search. This array could have up to 1 - 10000 ids and other filters as well. Is the recommended way to filter based on id´s like this?

```
$filter=Id eq 'ID1' or Id eq 'ID2'
```

Also I have tride it and I usually hit the filter limit which result in an error
so is there anothere way of filtering the search results based on an array of ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OData `search.in` function available in Azure Cognitive Search instead of writing this big OR filter. In fact it is the recommended approach.

You can learn more about this function here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-search-in-function.

Comment: I think even using this approach, there's some limitation around how many ids you can use inside the in function

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio - The documentation does not mention any limitations however you can run into URI length limitation if you use `GET` to do the search. With Azure Cognitive Search, it is also possible to pass the search request parameters via `POST` request as well.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio - This is what I found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-filter#filter-size-limitations.

Comment: @GauravMantri this is what I was facing so I used the post to send the filter in the body which solved my problem so thanks a lot